# what does sequence of random variable converge in first moment mean?

Tags: probability

> Give an example of $\{Xn, n ≥ 1\}$ and $X$ so that $Xn → X$ a.s., but
>   $Xn \nrightarrow X$ in the first moment.

So my question is what does it mean to converge in first moment?

Also, converge a.s means $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(\{w\in \Omega|X_n(w)\neq X(w)\})=0$?

I have hard time understanding difference between convergence in probability and convergence a.s as well. Convergence in probability means the region where $X_n$ and $X$ differ by more than $\epsilon$ is going to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. So then convergence a.s just take the $\epsilon$ in the definition of convergence in probability to be $0$?

Comment: Do you know what the first moment means ?

Comment: so i guess the first moment is $E(X)$, and $n^{th}$ moment is $E(X^n)$? Help!

Answer (score 1):

Almost sure convergence does not mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}P(\{w\in \Omega|X_n(w)\neq X(w)\})=0$. It means there is an event $E$ such that $P(E)=1$ and $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in E$.

Convergence in the first moment means $E|X_n-X| \to 0$.

Let $\Omega =(0,1), \mathcal F$ be the Borel sigma algebra and $P$ be Lebesgue measure. Let $X_n(w)=n$ if $\omega <\frac 1 n$ and $0$ otherwise.Let $X(\omega)=0$ for all $\omega$. Then $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ but $E|X_n-X|=1$ for all $n$. So $X_n \to X$ almsot surely but not in the first moment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb P(X_n = 0) = 1 - 1/n^2$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=2^n)=1/n^2$, then $X_n\to 0$ almost surely but $\mathbb E[X_n] = 2^n/n^2\to\infty$.